# Using Multiple Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Can I use multiple Xslt to create a single output xml file.

In my project, I need separate Xsl files for fonts, images, layout etc. So, is it possible to transform a single document with multiple xslt files into a single transformed xml document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you combine xslt using two specific elements.

Choice 1. `<xsl:import>`

`<xsl:import href="fonts.xsl"/>`

In this case the imported stylesheet will have lower precendece that the importing one.

Choice 2. `<xsl:include>`

`<xsl:include href="fonts.xsl"/>`

In this case you will include the contents of fonts.xsl into your main xsl. It's a real merge.

For more information have a look at [Combining Stylesheets with Include and Import](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/01/xslt/index.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can do it in this way ,Thank You for the replay

Comment: Do note that through `xsl.import` XSLT implements "inheritance" (`xsl:apply-imports` works as super class invocation) and through `xsl:include` you just have modularization.